# Powershell/ Print by filename

Tags: powershell

My English may not be perfect but I do my best.

I'm trying to write a Powershell script where the filename has a number at the end and it should print exactly that often.
Is this somehow possible ?
With the script it prints it only 1 time.
For whatever reason..

```
param (
    [string]$file = "C:\Scans\temp\*.pdf",
    [int]$number_of_copies = 1
)
foreach ($onefile in (Get-ChildItem $file -File)) {
    $onefile -match '\d$' | Out-Null
    for ($i = 1; $i -le [int]$number_of_copies; $i++) {
        cmd /C "lpr -S 10.39.33.204 -P optimidoc ""$($onefile.FullName)"""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for parameter `$number_of_copies` when the number of times it should be printed is taken from the file's BaseName anyway.

I would change your code to:

```
param (
    [string]$path = 'C:\Scans\temp'
)

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*.pdf' -File | 
    # filter only files that end with a number and capture that number in $matches[1]
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '(\d+)$' } |
    # loop through the files and print 
    ForEach-Object {
        for ($i = 1; $i -le [int]$matches[1]; $i++) {
            cmd /C "lpr -S 10.39.33.204 -P optimidoc ""$($_.FullName)"""
        }
    }
```

Inside the `ForEach-Object`, on each iteration, the `$_` automatic variable represents the current FileInfo object.

P.S. Your script prints each file only once because you set parameter `$number_of_copies` to `1` as default value, but the code never changes that to the number found in the file name.

BTW. Nothing wrong with your English